# ODocument save doesn't throws Exception if the record is not inserted into database

Tags: java, orientdb

I have problems with java Document API. We are using version 2.1.9.

Sometimes, randomly, I cannot save an ODocument into database (with or without transaction) without catching a specific exception from the database.

Here is the code used to save the ODocument:

```
try { 
    ODocument od = attachedObject.toDocument(); 
    ORecord record = connection.save(od);       
    attachedObject.setOriginalRecord(record); 
    return attachedObject; 
} catch (Exception e) { 
    if(e instanceof OConcurrentModificationException) { 
       throw new ConcurrentModificationException(e); 
    } if(e instanceof ONeedRetryException) { throw e; } 
}
```

`connection` is an instance of `ODatabaseDocumentTx`;

`attachedObject` is our entity bean that can be converted to a `ODocument` Object.

Comment: What is the exception? Can you post the code ?

Comment: The API (Document JAVA API) doesn't throw an exception seems work correctly, but when we try to query the created record it doesn't exist.

Comment: I understand, to reproduce your problem I need the code whereby you save an ODocument into database and the query

Comment: But you seem not to be logging the exception if different than  ConcurrentModificationException or ONeedRetryException... put in a log or system.out

Comment: In the code snippet I omitted the not issue related code pieces,
actually the full catch code is:

`} catch (Exception e) { 
    log.error("Error saving object", e, null);
    if(e instanceof OConcurrentModificationException) { 
       throw new ConcurrentModificationException(e); 
    } if(e instanceof ONeedRetryException) { throw e; } 
}`
In case of OConcurrentModificationException or ONeedRetryException we also propagate the exception.

Comment: Can you post more code about attachedObject ?